# nicEdit Uploading Locally - Issues with nicUpload

Tags: nicedit

If anyone has managed to get locally uploading images I'd be mightily appreciative of some help.

I've downloaded the latest version of nicEdit along with the nicUpload plug in (from nicedit.com - Version 0.9 r24 released June 7th, 2012).

I've also downloaded nicUpload.php from http://svn.nicedit.com//trunk/nicUpload/php/nicUpload.php

NicUpload.php - I've set NICUPLOAD_PATH and NICUPLOAD_URI both to 'images' which is the subfolder of where nicupload.php and nicEdit.js are located.

NicEdit.js - I've added the following to line 271:-

```
uploadURI : 'nicUpload.php?id=123',
```

I've given it an ID otherwise it was failing with an invalid ID code. But the ?id=123 isn't meant to be there. I've also set the iconsPath accordingly.

Line 1370 I've switched this:-

```
nicURI : 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json',
```

for this:-

```
nicURI : 'http://www.mydomain.com/nicedit/nicUpload.php',
```

But I'm still getting "Failed to upload image". I've searched and searched and searched for answers to this and I'm getting close to having spent two days tinkering with it.

With a few debugging displays I can see that it's failing on line 46 of nicUpload.php where it says:-

$file = $_FILES['nicImage'];
$image = $file['tmp_name'];

$max_upload_size = ini_max_upload_size();
if(!$file) {...

That last IF is true and that's where it exits with the error.

Appreciate anyone being able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The nicUpload.php script file laying around sucks and I don't even understand how it could work.

NicEditor uses imgur as the default image upload service. The source code follows the API format described here: http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#upload

My suggestion would be to implement the API request and response defined there.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use the niceedit upload function to do what you want. I managed to add a button to the link and img dropdown menu. The button opens a file manager window where you also can upload. I managed to put then de url of the image or document into the nicedit drop down img or url window. That is how I solved the problem.